# Modifying variables in subclass instances

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, screeps

I've become hopelessly addicted to Screeps recently, and I refactored some code to make a task-based implementation. Tasks are things like "walk to and then harvest until you are at full capacity" and are based off of a single base task template written as an ES6-style class. Creeps can be assigned tasks through a wrapper (tasks.js) that loads the relevant task file and returns a new task instance.

Today I ran into a strange bug that makes me think I don't fully understand Javascript's inheritance model. Below is the relevant code:

Task.js: (base task class)

```
class Task {
    constructor(taskName) {
        // Parameters for the task
        this.name = taskName; // name of task
        this.quiet = false; // suppress console logging if true
        this.creep = [creep assigned to this task]
        this.target = [thing task operates on, e.g. "repair this wall"]
        ...
    }
    ...
    // Execute this task each tick. Returns nothing unless work is done.
    step() {
        ...
        if (creep.pos.inRangeTo(target, this.targetRange)) {
            var workResult = this.work();
            console.log(this.quiet) // < returns false, should be true?
            if (workResult != OK && this.quiet == false) {
                creep.log("Error: " + workResult); // < is printed when run
            }
            return workResult;
        } [else move to target]
    }
    ...
    // Task to perform when at the target
    work() {
        // overwrite this in child class
    }
}

module.exports = Task;
```

task_harvest.js: (harvesting task)

```
var Task = require('Task');

class taskHarvest extends Task {
    constructor() {
        super('harvest');
        // no mention of this.quiet here
    }
    ...
    work() {
        console.log("harvest:" + this.quiet);
        return this.creep.harvest(this.target);
    }
}
module.exports = taskHarvest;
```

tasks.js: (wrapper to generate a new task instance via a function call)

```
module.exports = function (taskName) {
    var TaskClass = require('task_' + taskName); // all tasks follow this naming pattern
    var taskInstance = new TaskClass;
    return taskInstance;
};
```

harvester.js: (behavior model for a harvester creep)

```
var tasks = require('tasks');
var roleHarvester = {
    ...
    harvest: function (creep) {
        var target = Game.getObjectById(creep.memory.assignment);
        var taskHarvest = tasks('harvest');
        taskHarvest.quiet = true;  // < this task shouldn't print anything
        creep.assign(taskHarvest, target); // assigns to creep.task
        return OK;
    },
    ...
    run: function (creep) { // executed every tick
        // execute the task
        creep.task.step();
    },
   ...
}
```

When I assign a creep to harvest from a source, I create a new task from task_harvest.js, set its `quiet` property to be `true`, and bind it and its target to the creep. Once the creep has a task it is instructed to run it until it becomes invalid (code not included above). The creep executes the task fine, but it still logs everything to the console.

I would think that in harvester.js, when I set `taskHarvest.quiet = true;`, the behavior imported from Task.js would see `this.quiet` as `true`. However, it seems as though that is not the case. In `roleHarvester`, running `console.log(creep.task.quiet)` returns `true`, but in `Task`, running `console.log(this.quiet)` when the creep is executing the assigned task gives `false`.

I could add `quiet` into the constructor as an optional parameter, but that's convoluted and I want to know why what I'm doing isn't working.

Comment: When you are checking the value of `this.quiet` are you 100% sure that `this` is correct?  I don't see anything obviously wrong or misunderstood about your inheritance.  Setting `taskHarvest.quiet = true;` should work just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 in Task.js, `this` should refer to `Task`, and in task_harvest.js, `this` should refer to `taskHarvest`, which doesn't define `this.quiet`, so it should refer to inherited Task.js variable. Then when I create an instance of `taskHarvest` and set its `instance.quiet = true`, it doesn't seem to be changing the inherited value from `Task`. If I do `console.log(instance.quiet)`, it returns `true`, but if I got to `Task` and do `console.log(this.quiet)`, it returns `false`.

Comment: I didn't ask you what it "should" be.  I asked you what it actually was.  There's only two possibilities here.  Something else is setting `.quiet` back to `false` or you aren't looking at the same object sometime later.  YOU have to figure out which of those it is.  You don't show enough of your code for us to follow the lifetime of the object and everything that could happen to it.  For example, I have no idea what `creep.assign()` does.  It could be copying the object, setting some properties on it, etc...

Comment: FYI, you could add a special property for debugging purposes like `taskHarvest._test = "hello";` and then see if that property still exists in `step()` with `console.log("_test:", this._test)` just to see if you still have the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it actually wasn't an inheritance problem; it was a problem caused by the game mechanics: `taskHarvest.quiet` wasn't getting deleted each tick. Screeps only allows you to store JSON-serializable objects in memory, so I store the task settings in memory and reconstruct the task object each tick:

```
Object.defineProperty(Creep.prototype, 'task', {
    get: function () { // provide new task object recreated from literals stored in creep.memory.task
        if (this.memory.task != null) {
            var task = tasks(this.memory.task.name);
            task.creepName = this.memory.task.creepName;
            task.targetID = this.memory.task.targetID;
            task.data = this.memory.task.data; // < task.quiet is now task.data.quiet
            return task;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },
    set: function(newTask) {
        if (newTask != null) {
            this.log("use Creep.assign() to assign tasks. Creep.task = ___ should only be used to null a task.");
        } else {
            this.memory.task = newTask;
        }
    }
});
```

`taskHarvest.quiet` wasn't getting stored in memory, so it wouldn't persist past the first tick of the task. I now store all instance-level adjustable parameters in a `task.data` object, so `task.quiet` is now `task.data.quiet`. This fixed the problem; sorry for producing any confusion!